# How to create custom gallery view and zoom?

Tags: android

How to create own Gallery View?
i want to view multiple images and scroll.

Thank you,
Rajesh Patil

Answer (score 0):

As I understand correctly you need to create your custom `Gallery` view. You need to extend it from `AdapterView`. [There is](http://developer.sonyericsson.com/wp/2010/05/20/android-tutorial-making-your-own-3d-list-part-1/) a great example of how to do that, but in custom `ListView` interpretation by SonyEricsson. You may use it to figure out how to create custom `Gallery`

Comment: No sir,i want to create own gallery view